# Grails pass params to image

Tags: image, grails, parameters

How can i get i have an image, inside a each tag load dynamically by name, something like this:

```
 <g:link controller="conferenceUser"><img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'solr.png')}" height="100px" width="200px"/></g:link>
```

but instead of file:'solr.png', have ${it.xxx} like this:

```
<g:link controller="conferenceUser"><img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'${it.xxx}.png')}" height="100px" width="200px"/></g:link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is already in a Groovy scripting block you can reference the variable and then use the Java-style String concatenation:

```
src="${resource(dir:'images',file:it.xxx + '.png')}"
```